# Finding an operator in terms of creation and annihilation operators that satisfy some conditions

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, harmonic-oscillator, quantum-optics, coherent-states

I have a problem where I'm looking to find the following Hermitian operator $\hat{A}$ written in terms of the operators $\hat{a}^{\dagger}\hat{a}$, $\hat{a}^2$, $\hat{a}^{\dagger 2}$, $\hat{a}$, $\hat{a}^{\dagger}$, and $\mathbb{1}$ with coefficients $c_1$, $c_2$, $c_3$, and $c_4$ respectively as follows (${c_2,c_3}\in \mathbb{C}$ and ${c_1,c_4}\in\mathbb{R}$).

> $\hat{A}=c_1 \hat{a}^\dagger \hat{a} + c_2 \hat{a}^2 + c_2^* \hat{a}^{\dagger 2} + c_3 \hat{a} + c_3^* \hat{a}^\dagger + c_4 \mathbb{1} \tag{1}$

$\hat{A}$ is such that it satisfies the following operator equation

> $\frac{\hat{A}\rho+\rho\hat{A}}{2}=-\sum_{n=0}^{N} \frac{n}{2} k_n(\hat{a}^{\dagger}\vert in\Delta\rangle\langle i n \Delta\vert+\vert in\Delta\rangle\langle in\Delta\vert\hat{a}) \tag{2}$

in the limit when $N \Delta >>1$.

Note that $\vert i n \Delta\rangle$ is a coherent state and $N$ and $\Delta$ are parameters of the system. $\rho= \sum_{n=0}^{N} k_n\vert i n \Delta\rangle\langle i n \Delta\vert$ is a mixed state.

Defining $\alpha=in \Delta$ and using the relations:

> $\hat{a}^{\dagger}\hat{D}(\alpha)=\hat{D}(\alpha)(\hat{a}^{\dagger}+\alpha^{*}) \tag{3}$

> $\hat{D}^{\dagger}(\alpha)\hat{a}=(\hat{a}+\alpha)\hat{D}^{\dagger}(\alpha) \tag{4}$

I rewrote $(2)$ as follows

> $\frac{\hat{A}\rho+\rho\hat{A}}{2}=-\sum_{n=0}^{N} \frac{n}{2} k_n(\vert\alpha,1\rangle\langle\alpha\vert+\vert\alpha\rangle\langle\alpha,1\vert) \tag{5}$

where, $\vert\alpha,1\rangle=\hat{D}(\alpha)\hat{a}^{\dagger}\vert0\rangle=\hat{D}(\alpha)\vert1\rangle$ is the displaced number state.

After finding the operator $\hat{A}$, I need to calculate its variance with respect to $| \alpha \rangle$ as follows.

> $\sigma^2_{\hat{A}} = \langle 0 | \hat{A}^2 | 0 \rangle - \langle 0 | \hat{A} | 0 \rangle^2 \tag{6}$

Finally, $\sigma^2_{\hat{A}}$ would be used to obtain an analytical formula which will be further used to fit some numerical data I have. Moreover, the best fit to the numerical data among these corresponds to the operator $\hat{A}=\frac{i}{2\Delta}(\hat{a}^2-\hat{a}^{\dagger 2})$ with $\sigma^2_{\hat{A}}=\frac{1}{2\Delta^2}+n^2$.

However, the best possible fit seem to occur when there is no $n$ but only $\Delta$ dependency in the variance. I'm stuck in finding solutions that corresponds to this case (if it actually exists). Any ideas on how to approach this would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: You say $n\Delta \gg 1$ and also that $\Delta$ is very large compared to $n$; which one is it? Or is it actually both?

Comment: I recommend trying it for a single $k_n$ and seeing what the equations produce. For example it looks like $c_2=0$ helps, as does $0=2c_4+\alpha c_3+\alpha^* c_3$

Comment: If $\alpha$ was real this would easily be solved by setting $c_2=c_3=c_4=0$. So maybe there's a rotation of coordinates you can perform to solve this, or maybe you can be happy with a minus sign instead of a $+$ in (2)

Comment: @QuantumMechanic Only $n \Delta >>1$. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Don’t you rather mean $N\Delta \gg 1$? $n$ is a dummy variable. Are the $k_n$ arbitrary? $A$ could depend a priori on the values of the $k_n$…

Comment: @Ipz Yes, I do mean $N \Delta>>1$. Corrected. Also, $k_n$ are arbitrary coefficients.

Comment: @lpz this confuses me too. Either $n$ or $N$ is a parameter defining $\alpha$, yet they each also play different roles (the dummy index or the maximum index of the sum)

Comment: Thanks for the edits. If the coefficients $k_n$ are arbitrary then one should not be able to impose any conditions on $N$ (I can always make $N$ arbitrarily large by defining $k_n=0$ for higher and higher terms). This means that $N\Delta\gg 1$ can trivially be satisfied for any $\Delta$ without actually imposing a constraint on the system

Comment: Also your expression should have $\alpha^* |\alpha,1\rangle\langle\alpha|+\alpha |\alpha\rangle\langle\alpha,1|$, which don't cancel even though $\alpha^*=-\alpha$ because $ |\alpha,1\rangle\langle\alpha|\neq  |\alpha\rangle\langle\alpha,1|$

Comment: @QuantumMechanic I have now solved the issue I had been facing. I noticed a mistake in my calculation that the variance must be taken with respect to the vacuum state $\vert 0\rangle$ instead of the coherent state $\vert\alpha\rangle$ as written previously. Now, I get the expected expression for the variance i.e., $\sigma^2_{\hat{A}}=\frac{1}{2\Delta^2}$ from the operator $\hat{A}=\frac{i}{2\Delta}(\hat{a}^2-\hat{a}^{\dagger 2})$ (constructed from $(2)$). Thank you for your efforts.